# Chrome extension not working with angular JS

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome-extension

I am developing an ERP with angular, in which every phone number needs to be callable when vonage extension is installed.

but this extension is not working because angular creates the data on state change and i am guessing chromes extension works on page load event.
any workaround for this problem?

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {      
  $scope.phone= '(123)-2343-2432';
});
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    {{phone}}
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Tell us more about how are you implementing the extension functionality - are u using a content script or an injected script or background page??

Comment: this extension automatically searchs for the phone number on the page and make a little button beside it to call. but its not working since angular renders the data after page load.

Comment: So you are using a content script to search for a phone number and adding a button?? by using angularjs ??

Comment: extension is doing that.i am just printing the phone number by angular.

Comment: can you share the code with us?

Comment: @Sid updated the code

Comment: Simply use MutationObserver to detect the changes in DOM.

Comment: @wOxxOm i am not developing the extension. i am just trying to understand which event to fire on data load from angular so that extension will re render its script to detect the phone number.

Comment: It depends on how that extension's content script is listening to the changes. Which vonage extension of the three present in the web store do you target?

Comment: @wOxxOm this is the link:    https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/click-to-dial-from-vonage/ildccibmanndgalianjghiompgkcmkli?hl=en

Comment: They use the ancient and currently deprecated DOMSubtreeModified event, which supposedly should still work in the browsers and detect any changes you make. I don't see any other modification listeners in the extension. Consider suggesting its authors to use MutationObserver instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149987/discussion-between-gaurav-srivastava-and-woxxom).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that extension detects changes in the page by listening to DOMSubtreeModified event, which has been deprecated long time ago due to the performance issues. For some reason this event isn't triggered in your case.

You can explicitly fire the event in your page script:

```
document.dispatchEvent(new Event('DOMSubtreeModified', {bubbles: true}));
```